# How do I determine the value of an symbolic path

Tags: macos, wget, symlink, lynx

When I use "lynx" via the terminal I believe it is using an symbolic link, but my Google searches have failed to show me how to determine the symbolic path value.

That is, I would like to determine the symbolic link value for "lynx", and a few others, e.g. wget, etc.

Thanks for any insights and suggestions.

P.S. I am using the terminal on a Mac machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
readlink `which lynx`
```

`which` does not follow symbolic links. Instead, it gets only to the symbolic link which got executed. `readlink` can then follow this symbolic link to the original binary/executable.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
 ls -l `which lynx`
```

which will exhibit the linked path (at least on some `ls`s).